# Temporary network interfaces created for a hot-plugged USB-Ethernet adapter

Tags: network-interface, udev, usb-device, hot-plug

I'm very new to udev and the hotplug system of Linux.

When I plug in an USB-Ethernet-Adapter to an USB-port of my system the following uevents are fired by the kernel to udev (monitored by the `udevadm monitor --udev` command):

```
UDEV  [38401.799873] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.804433] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.807404] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.809279] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.824694] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0 (net)
UDEV  [38401.826048] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1 (net)
UDEV  [38401.828327] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38401.830001] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38401.831322] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38401.831460] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38401.833877] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.833947] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38401.841282] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.148462] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38404.148700] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38404.150532] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0/net/eth0 (net)
UDEV  [38404.187625] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38404.187679] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38404.188029] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.189612] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1/net/eth1 (net)
UDEV  [38404.190755] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.242922] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.245161] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:2.1 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.256518] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38404.265373] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38406.287188] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38406.291238] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38406.294413] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38406.335093] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/enxf8e43b4f4bd2 (net)
UDEV  [38406.338892] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/eth0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38406.338958] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/eth0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [38406.342103] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [38406.349754] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [38407.211581] move     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/enxf8e43b4f4bd2 (net)
```

The question is: why are the (temporary) interfaces *eth0* and *eth1* created, removed, and then "substituted" by the final network device *enxf8e43b4f4bd2*?

Background: I am working with the sd-event API of systemd and trying to identify the moment when a hot-plugged USB Ethernet adapter can actually be fully used. As seen in the output above, many uevents are fired until the final network device is available.

So, why are so many uevents fired for the USB Ethernet adapter? Is it because USB Ethernet adapters typically have two interfaces, one for the Ethernet connection and one for the control and management of the device, and thus the kernel first creates *eth0* and *eth1* before unifying them into a single interface called *enxf8e43b4f4bd2*?